# Migration from “Focal Point Field" for Craft to Native Craft 3 image focal point

Tags: migration

Is there a migration from the “Focal Point Field for Craft“ plugin to the Craft3 native focal point? Or has anyone tried this themselves?

Answer (score 2):

The inherent problem that you're going to have is that Craft CMS 3 focal points are *per asset*, and Focal Point Field is *per field*.

So you could have multiple Focal Point Fields that have different Focal Points for the same Asset... and then how would you map them?

A migration could be done, but there would have to be some compromise to take the above into account.

Comment: Yeah, that is a good point. But, i still need to get the data over for this upgrade! I'll have to get coding. Thanks Andrew!

Comment: Andrew's point is well made but if you're mainly using focalpoints in one context, then I wrote a quick and nasty hack thing that will move over the values for you - see https://github.com/aelvan/FocalPointField-Craft/issues/12